# dataAdapter.Fill is very slow

Tags: database, vb.net, fill, dataadapter

When i run this code it gets really slow at dataAdapter.Fill(db) and i have no idea why, it may take up to like 90 sec.

Anyone know what might cause it to be so slow?

Here's some of the projects code:

```
Select Case frmLoggIn.txtLoggInProdGrupp.Text
    Case "4"
        SˆkDatum = WeekSettings(Date.Today.ToString, 2)
        sSql = "SELECT MP64001 AS TO_nr, MP64002 AS Art_nr, CASE WHEN LEN(KOMMENTAR) > 0 THEN '##' + SC01002 ELSE SC01002 END AS Art_ben, MP64004 AS P_Ant, MP67040 AS R_Ant, MP67032 AS Plan_Start, MP64001 AS Start, MP67033 AS Plan_Klar, MP64001 AS Klar, MP64013 AS Lev_Datum, MP64001 AS Lev, CASE MP67058 WHEN '0' THEN 'Skapad' WHEN '1' THEN 'Ej startad' WHEN '3' THEN 'Startad' WHEN '4' THEN 'Avbruten' WHEN '5' THEN 'Avslutad' END AS Status , MP64001 AS SlaskPlat, CASE WHEN LEN(MP67068) = 0 THEN PERSON ELSE MP67068 END AS Pers, LTRIM(RTRIM(MP64017)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(MP64018)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(MP64019)) AS Kommentar, MP64088 AS TO_Status, MP64034 AS TO_Prio, MP67010*MP64004 AS P_Tid, COMPOK AS IOK, MP67035 AS R_Time, MP67003 AS OP_Number " & _
        "FROM WOTransComments0000 RIGHT JOIN (SC01" & CompanyNumber & "00 INNER JOIN (MP64" & CompanyNumber & "00 INNER JOIN MP67" & CompanyNumber & "00 ON MP64001 = MP67001) ON SC01001 = MP64002) ON OP = MP67006 AND WO = MP67001 " & _
        "WHERE (((MP67033)<='" & SˆkDatum & "') AND ((MP67058)<5) AND ((MP67006)='" & frmLoggIn.txtLoggInProdGrupp.Text & "'))" & _
        "ORDER BY MP67032, MP64001" 

End Select

GridShowOrders.DataSource = OpenDataTable(sSql) 'H‰mtar data 

Call GridSettings() 'Sub-rutin fˆr formatering av DataGridView


Module Module1

Friend connstr As String = "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=MarcoscalaDB;UID=marcoscala;PWD=scala"


Friend Function OpenDataTable(ByVal sqlstr As String)
        Try
            'SearchOK = True
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
            Dim db As New DataTable()
            Dim dataAdapter As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sqlstr, connstr)
            dataAdapter.ToString()
            dataAdapter.Fill(db)
            dataAdapter.Dispose()
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            Return db
        Catch e As Exception
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            If InStr(e.Message, "42S02", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
                MsgBox(e.Message)
                'SearchOK = False
                Return ""
                Exit Function
            End If
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            MsgBox(e.Message)
            'SearchOK = False
            Return ""
        End Try
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Use `using` as it is better at managing resources. Does your query take long to run when you run it directly on the server?

Comment: I haven't tested this specific program on the server but everything else on the server runs at good speed on the server. @DanielShillcock

Comment: I'd guess inefficient query or lack of indexes, but unless you test it directly to confirm it's slow there you would just be guessing.

Comment: How many records are being searched in total?

Comment: Debug.print (sSQL) then cut n paste into SSMS then examine the query plan

Comment: Executing SQL via Management Studio doesn't always use the same execution plan as executing it via code.  SQL Server has a lot of black magic under-the-hood.  But it can give you a rough idea of where an issue might lie.